# Django: How to get most recent object from different model?

Tags: python, django

I m trying to display following output in which Cylinder, Issue & Return are different model, the view I m expecting is cylinder table, where only recently created entries of issue and return is appearing ,
For example :

cylinderId=100 having two entries in issue table and return table but in cylinder table only the recently created is appearing which is :-

```
cyId |   createdAt |  issuedDate  | username  | ReturnDate

100  |   5may,13:00|  6may,14:00  | anyone    | 7may,15:00
```

here is models:-

```
class Cylinder(models.Model):
    stachoice=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty') 
    ]
    substachoice=[
    ('Available','available'), 
    ('Unavailable','unavailable'),
    ('Issued','issued') 
    
    ]
    cylinderId=models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True,null=False)
    gasName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cylinderSize=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=stachoice,default='fill')
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=substachoice,default="Available")
    EntryDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cylinderDetail',args=[(self.cylinderId)])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cylinderId)

class Issue(models.Model):
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('Cylinder',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=60,null=False)
    issueDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk: 
            if self.cylinder.Availability=='Available':
                Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability=('Issued'))

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        
    def __str__(self):
        
        return str(self.userName) 


class Return(models.Model):
    fill=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty'),
    ('refill','Refill')
    ]

    ava=[
    ('yes','YES'),
    ('no','NO')
    ]
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('Cylinder',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    availability=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=ava)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=fill)
    returnDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:

            if self.cylinder.Availability=='Issued':
                
                if self.availability=='YES' or self.availability=='yes':
                    Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Available')
                    if self.status=='empty' or self.status=='Empty':
                        Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Empty')
                else:
                    Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Unavailable')
                    if self.status=='refill' or self.status=='Refill':
                        Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Refill')
                    if self.status=='empty' or self.status=='Empty':
                        Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Empty')


        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cylinder)
```

view:-

```
def cylinderListView(request):
    
    cylinder=Cylinder.objects.pefetch_related().order_by('-EntryDate')
    
    return render(request,'entry/cylinderList.html',locals())
```

template cylinderList.html:-

```
{%for cy in cylinder %}
                    <tr bgcolor="#e6f0ff" align="center">
                        
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50"><a style="border-width: 0px" href="{{cy.get_absolute_url}}">{{cy.cylinderId}}<a></td>
               
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{cy.EntryDate}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{cy.gasName}}</td>
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">
                    {{cy.cylinderSize}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">
                    {{cy.Status}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{cy.Availability}}</td>

               
                {% if cy.issue_set.all%}
                
                {% for issue in cy.issue_set.all %}

               
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{issue.issueDate}}</td>
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{issue.userName}}</td>
                
               {% endfor %}
                
                {% else %}
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">-</td>
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">-</td>

                {% endif%}


                 {% if cy.return_set.all%}
                
                {% for return in cy.return_set.all %}
                
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{return.returnDate}}</td>
              
               {% endfor %}
                
                {% else %}
                
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">-</td>

                {% endif%}


                                    
                
                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>

            {% else %}
```

Here is the view i m expecting:-

[image]

for this result what should i do? Help please :)

Comment: Please add your models to the question.

Comment: @ShagunRaghav just to clarify, you want to get the latest issue and return rows for each cylinder?

Comment: @yovelcohen YES

Comment: You should use prefetch_related to accomplish this. Please read the documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın I have done this relation but I had a problem when I fetched the issue by loop it will return all issue entry respective cylinder id ,and what i want, as you can see in the picture that the issue table can have multiple entries for same cylinder id (distinct by date&time) and in cylinder table the issue entry which is created recently with respect of their cylinder id is appearing,

Comment: I can't help you if you don't add the code you just created for this query. Please add it to the question so that we can fix that together.

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest) method

```
Cylinder.objects.latest('EntryDate')
```

This will return the latest Cylinder object in the table based on the `CreatedAt` field.

If you want to list the latest Cylinders then use

```
Cylinder.objects.all().order_by('-EntryDate')
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention :), but it will only return single cylinder entry and  i want to display all cylinder id with their respective latest entries in issue table and return table.

Comment: Not resulting in expected ouutput.

Comment: So if I try to fetch issue entries(cylinder_obj.issue_set.all()) , It will return all issued entries created for that cylinder id , and as you can see in picture(i have attached in my question) issue table can have multiple entries for single cylinder id( for eg: cylinder Id =100) , but i only want the entry which is recently created for cylinder id ,but instead executing this query will returning me all entries.

Answer (score 0):

simply query them as `Cylinder.objects.order_by('-pk')`

Comment: By executing this query do i m able to fetch issue entries and return entries as well? If yes then How?

Comment: you can query `Issue` entries of a single `Cylinder`  as `cylinder_obj.issue_set.all()`.
if you want all **issue** entries of the **cylinder** list you got, then it's possible via `for` loop. and it's the same for `Return` too.

Comment: By querying this  for issue and return , it will return all entries created for that cylinder id (cylinderId=pk) but i want only one entries which is recently created for that particular cylinder id. Please observe the table picture i have been added.

Comment: just use `cylinder_obj.issue_set.order_by('-pk')` for 3 last objects you can do
 `list(cylinder_obj.issue_set.order_by('-pk'))[:-3]`